# Get conditional values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I have a JavaScript layer for my HTML which has its first 3 rows presented below:

```
var TR_Accomodation = {
    'Hacı Sabancı': {
      'İl': 'ADANA',
      'Dist': 100,
      'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
      'Count': 52
    },
    'Ceyhan': {
      'İl': 'ADANA',
      'Dist': 100,
      'Accomodation_Type': 'motel',
      'Count': 25
    },
    'Ceyhan': {
      'İl': 'ADANA',
      'Dist': 50,
      'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
      'Count': 31
    }, ...
```

dataset has 8000 rows, 81 distinct values for "İl", 4 for "Dist" and 6 in my html I have a listener by drop down list to get İl values and the second one to get the features 'Ceyhan' so on.

How can I get the values for each dist value and each Accomodation_Type.

In detail, I want to have variables like Dist_50km_hotel so that presents the e.g. number of hotels at most distance of 50 km of Ceyhan.

How can I extract Count value for feature Ceyhan where the "Dist" is 50 and 'Accomodation_Type' is equal to "hotel" and save that in a new variable.

Comment: How is this data stored? A database and query language of some sort would be perfect for extracting such data.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+maps+distance+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You have two keys on the same object level with the same name `Ceyhan`. This will definitely not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to an array using Object Entries. That will let you filter it based on the object. After that you convert it back to your object format.

```js
const TR_Accomodation = {
  'Hacı Sabancı': {
    'İl': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 100,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
    'Count': 52
  },
  'Ceyhan': {
    'İl': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 100,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'motel',
    'Count': 25
  },
  'Ceyhan2': {
    'İl': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 50,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
    'Count': 31
  }
}

const filterByDistance = km => {
  // change to an array
  const placesInArray = Object.entries(TR_Accomodation);
  // filter based on distance
  const filteredPlaces = placesInArray.filter(([k, details]) => details.Dist <= km);
  //change back to your object format
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredPlaces);
};

const withIn50 = filterByDistance(50);
const withIn100 = filterByDistance(100);

console.log(withIn50);
console.log(withIn100);
```

Comment: Should note that in the data I changed the one `Ceyhan` to `Ceyhan2` because you can't have dupes. I figured it was a data entry thing for demo. If you do have dupes than your code is never doing to work because you can't have multiple keys with the same name in an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your structure to an array since an object cannot have the same 2 keys:

```js
{
const TR_Accomodation = [{
    Location: 'Hacı Sabancı',
    '': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 100,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
    'Count': 52
  },
  {
    Location:'Ceyhan',
    'İl': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 100,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'motel',
    'Count': 25
  },
  {
    Location:'Ceyhan',
    'İl': 'ADANA',
    'Dist': 50,
    'Accomodation_Type': 'hotel',
    'Count': 31
  }
]

const type = 'hotel';
const distance = 50;
const location = 'Ceyhan';

const count = TR_Accomodation.reduce((r, {Dist,Accomodation_Type, Location,Count}) => 
  (Dist <= distance && Accomodation_Type === type && (Location === location) && (r+=Count), r), 0);
  
console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: so thanks for your kindly responce. but unfortunatley, that does not work for me. in fact i have a huge code with 2000 lines and here the İl values And 'Ceyhan' liked values in fact are got from a listener from a drop down list.